# My javascript module is not working when I used gulp and browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, gulp, browserify

My javascript module is not working when I concat javscript files with gulp and browserify.

This is my module.

**LastestPost.js**

```
var PostBox = require('../objects/PostBox');

var LastestPosts = (function() {
    var btnLeft;
    var btnRight;

    var postBoxs = (function() {
        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
            var post_box = new PostBox();
            arr.push(post_box);
        }
        return arr;
    })();

    var index = 0;
    var lastIndex;


    return({
        initDOM: function($) {
            btnLeft = $('#btn-lastest-previous');
            btnRight = $('#btn-lastest-next');
            /* some codes */
        },
        initIndex: function() {
            if (index == 0) {
                /* some codes */
            }
            else if (index == lastIndex) {
                /* some codes */
            }
            else {
                /* some codes */
            }
        },
        getLastIndex: function() {
             $.get('/lastestposts-getlastindex', function(data) {
                lastIndex = data;
             });
        },
        updatePostBox: function() {
            var parameter = { index: index };

            $.get('/lastestposts-getindex', parameter, function(data) {
                /* some codes */
            });
        },
        increaseIndex: function() {
            if (index < lastIndex) {
                index++;
             }
         },
        decreaseIndex: function() {
            if (index > 0) {
                index--;
            }
         },
        getLeftBtn: function() {
             return btnLeft;
        },
        getRightBtn: function() {
            return btnRight;
        }
    });
 })();

 module.exports = LastestPosts;
```

**Main.js**

```
var LastestPosts = require('./module/LastestPosts');

$(document).ready(function() { 
    LastestPosts.initDOM($);
    LastestPosts.getLastIndex();
    LastestPosts.updatePostBox();
    LastestPosts.initIndex();

    (LastestPosts.getRightBtn()).click(function() {
        LastestPosts.increaseIndex();
        LastestPosts.initIndex();
        LastestPosts.updatePostBox();
    });
    (LastestPosts.getLeftBtn()).click(function() {
        LastestPosts.decreaseIndex();
        LastestPosts.initIndex();
        LastestPosts.updatePostBox();
    });
});
```

`btnLeft` and `btnRight` clicks well, but `LastestPosts.increaseIndex()` and `LastestPosts.initIndex()` are not working.

Before using gulp and browserify, I import each of javascript files like this.

```
<script src="./js/objects/PostBox.js"></script>
<script src="./js/module/Lastestposts.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

This works well, but after I concat javascript files with gulp and browserify, my javascript module doesn't work...

This is my gulp setting.

```
gulp.task('build-js', function () {
    return browserify('./public/src/js/main.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/dist/js'));
});
```

Please help this little student and sorry for my terrible english skill. I'm not good at english  :'(

Comment: Seems like I'm missing some code. Do you have everything in a repo somewhere? I'll give it a look in the next day or so.

Comment: Thank you very much :) You saved me. Here is git repo. https://github.com/seokju-na/blog-bang-extend.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly where things went wrong for you, but the issue came down to this error in the terminal -

```
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead app.js:107:9
```

Which meant that ultimately the problem was with this specific function not returning `lastIndex`:

```
getLastIndex: function() {
    $.get('/lastestposts-getlastindex', function(data) {
        lastIndex = data;
    });
},
```

If you modify your `res.send(4)` to be `res.send({lastIndex: 4});` and `getLastIndex()` to

```
getLastIndex: function() {
    $.get('/lastestposts-getlastindex', function(data) {
        lastIndex = data.lastIndex;
    });
},
```

Not sure why it was working prior - but currently your `lastIndex` private variable is `undefined` breaking everything - and this is why.

Comment: Wow! It works very well! You gave a lot of help in my web studying. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Often this problem appears from 'unclean' inline comments.

For example:

```
/*console.log('this will work');*/

/*

console.log('this might not work when minified');
*/
```

Try to remove all your comments and minify your code again.

Comment: Sorry to read that, after a couple of glances at your code, I can not see any syntax errors that could cause your code not to work when minified. Do you get any console errors that could point to the line that causes trouble when minified?

Comment: nope... I didn't get any errors. It's weird because when the files separated its works well, but after concat the files, LastestPosts.increaseIndex() and LastestPosts.initIndex() doesn't work.(index is not changing)